# OSX: Delete all matching certificates by command-line

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, security, osx

Using shell script to delete all matching certificates.

I found a list of certificates using:

```
security find-certificate -c "certificatename" -a -Z|grep SHA-1|awk '{ print $NF }'
```

Output is like this:

```
$ bash delete-cert.sh 
62D58774F9329FA1F96A2BB0C090130305B879ED
94B149CFDF32BDB1C9C28179FB586291167EC235
```

Now, I want to run the delete command on each of those `SHA-1` hashes, how can I do that?

```
sudo security delete-certificate -Z hash
```

I was doing like this,

```
hashes=$(security find-certificate -c "certificatename" -a -Z|grep SHA-1|awk '{ print $NF }')
for hash in $hashes; do
    echo deleting $hash
    sudo security delete-certificate -Z $hash
done
```

But I like the one line solution by #chaos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
security find-certificate -c "certificatename" -a -Z | \
  sudo awk '/SHA-1/{system("security delete-certificate -Z "$NF)}'
```

`awk` is called with `sudo`. `awk` then searches for the string `SHA-1` and calls the `security delete-certificate` command with the hash as argument. You have to provide the `sudo` password only once.